# WhatsApp Cloud API: Message fails with "More than 24 hours passed" error despite recent customer interaction

Tags: laravel, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm integrating the WhatsApp Cloud API into my application to send messages to customers. However, I'm encountering an issue where messages fail to send with the following error: "Message failed to send because more than 24 hours have passed since the customer last replied to this number."

The confusing part is that the customer has interacted with me just a few minutes ago. I've checked the timestamps and verified that the interaction occurred within the last 24 hours. Despite this, I keep receiving this error.